# How do I undo Rails template generation in Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I installed a new gem to my Rails project - 'phrasing' - which has gem dependencies on multiple Haml gems. I need the gem (it is adding some phenomenal functionality to my project), and need the dependencies to be installed, but now when I run `rails generate scaffold`, all of the view templates are generated in Haml rather than ERB. I need views to continue to be generated in ERB.

I reviewed several previous StackOverflow articles, but most focus on converting TO Haml, and the answers around making sure that ERB is the default generator refer to removing lines from the config files, which are not there in my case (it appears that the gems are controlling the default layout format somehow).

(**Note:** While I appreciate that there may be several advantages to using Haml, and I might consider using it in a new project, I'd like to keep this one consistent, and it's already 80% finished in ERB.)

Answer (score 4):

Turns out this was as simple as adding the following into `class Application` in the config/application.rb file:

```
config.generators do |g|
   g.template_engine :erb
end
```

Still not sure why the manual override was necessary, but it is. This fixes it.