# Scaffold creating .slim instead of erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that has been using `html.erb` files for a while now. Recently I noticed that my new scaffold are all coming into `.slim`. I see the invoke slim during the generation.

I would like to generate scaffold with views in `erb` if possible.

```
rails g scaffold_controller Welcome
```

My application.rb file:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'
require 'iconv'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)



module NewApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

I know this is a very simple question, but does not seem obvious on google. 
Thanks for help

Comment: Is there any "additional" code for the config generators in your application.rb file?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I just added the file. Thank you.

Comment: If you have the slim-rails gem added to your Gemfile, you'll maybe need to override the creation of haml files with every scaffold. Try something like `config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :erb
end` in your application.rb file.

Comment: That was quick! It is fixed. THANK YOU. You want to create a response so I validate it ?

Comment: You're welcome. It seems [`another user had the same problem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829169/5025116) you can +1 his/her answer.